# CHAT IM client (browser based, using JavaScript/jQuery and LAMP) like meebo or imo.im

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, chat

I am using imo.im for last few days. I want to make something with similar kind of functionality with LAMP and javascript/jquery.

I already have a table in MySQL with name as user_account_details. Where i have columns as userID, protocol, protocol_username, protocol_password, with values like these: `{123, facebook, 123_username, 123_password}` and so on..

I know the term **'protocol'** is not relevant here, but I can't think of anything else.

I don't need the complete code. I only want someone to show me the correct direction. I don't have any idea how to do this.. And how these multiple protocol chat clients works.

***Any reference LINK would be a great help...***

Is this very tough to do??

Thanks

Comment: numerous duplicates. use the search box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are looking for a PHP based application checkout [Jaxl library](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL). It contains [several sample application](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL/tree/master/app/) for getting started quickly. Specifically checkout echobot/sendMessage examples for command line based applications (basically bot). Check boshchat/boshMUChat examples for browser based application.

Comment: does jaxl supports multiple protocol?

Comment: no it doesn't... JAXL == Jabber XMPP Library ... so just xmpp